# DocuSign API - textTab appears as required when not set

Tags: docusignapi

I"m using the DocuSign API and have added a text tab for the recipient to enter their name. When they receive the email it appears as a required field - they can't continue unless they complete this field. However in my request I have not set this field to be mandatory/required.

Here's the data for the textTab:

```
"textTabs" : 
                [
                    {
                        "documentId" : "1",
                        "pageNumber" : "6",
                        "tabLabel" : "Name",
                        "xPosition" : "86",
                        "yPosition" : "273"
                    }
                ]
```

I haven't included the "required" parameter so not sure why this is appearing as a required field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not set "required" property for Text Tab then it is required in DocuSign. To make it optional, set `"required":"false"`

```
"textTabs" : 
                [
                    {
                        "documentId" : "12345",
                        "pageNumber" : "1",
                        "tabLabel" : "Name",
                        "xPosition" : "86",
                        "yPosition" : "273",
                        "required":"false"
                    }
                ]
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for that clarification - makes sense. Just wondering where this is documented as I couldn't find any reference to this? Can you share where you saw this in the API docs? Thanks